# Оптимизация, записи в файл

Tags: java, многопоточность, оптимизация

Что быстрее запишется, вывод разделенный на файлы или при записи в один файл?

Comment: Если запись осуществляется на один диск, то быстрее будет писать в один файл.

Answer (score 1):

Создание файла и его закрытие достаточно дорогие операции в смысле времени и ресурсов, так ответ самоочевиден: проще создать 1 файл и все писать в него.

Это легко проверяется: можно взять 100 файлов по 1 мегабайту и сравнить время их копирования по сравнению с 1 файлом размером 100 мегабайт.

Правда, как верно заметил в комментариях @SergeyGornostaev если файловая система виртуальная, то не факт, поскольку виртуальные файловые системы могут понимать под 1 файлом множество ресурсов на разных дисках/локациях - так что это надо учитывать.